# Convert date formatter to another date formatter

Tags: ios, swift, date

I have a date in string like this: `10/07/2016`

I want to convert like this: `10 July 2016`

I do like this:

```
struct NSDateFormatterType {
    static let API_FORMAT = "dd/mm/yyyy"
    static let DISPLAY_FORMAT = "dd MMMM yyyy"
}

extension NSDate {
  class func convertDateDisplayFormat(dateString: String) -> String {
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = NSDateFormatterType.API_FORMAT
    if let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateString) {
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = NSDateFormatterType.DISPLAY_FORMAT
        return dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date)
    } else {
        return dateString
    }
}
```

But it gives me: `10 January 2016`

What I do wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `API_FORMAT` `dd/mm/yyyy` format is wrong, `mm` is used for `Minute` you need to use `MM` for `Month`. So it must be like this `dd/MM/yyyy`

Comment: Thanks. It works now.

Answer (score 1):

Same conversion in **Swift 3.0** would be as following.

```
var dateString = "26/08/2016"
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()

// *** Format to read string date ***
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
if let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString) 
{
    // *** set output date format ***
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd MMMM yyyy"
    print("formatted date \(dateFormatter.string(from: date))")
} else {
    print("can't convert \(dateString)")
```